# Getting by value and reference. Ambiguity. Template functions

Tags: c++, templates

Please consider the following code:

```
template<typename Body>
Body solve(Body a, Body b){
    Body zero(0);
    return zero;  
}

template<typename Body, Body& zero>
Body solve(Body a, Body b){
    return zero;
}

complex<double> zero_complex(0);

int main() {
    complex<double> c1(1,2);
    complex<double> c2(3,4);    
    solve<complex<double>, zero_complex> (c1,c2);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get `complex<double>` by reference?

When I overload a function (see below) I get an ambiguity error.

```
template<typename Body>
Body solve(Body& a, Body& b){
    Body zero(0);
    return zero;  
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get the point. You want to add that overload to code above and it raises `ambigious blablabla`?

Comment: Tried to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [argument dependent lookup(ADL) or Koenig lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)

If 2 functions has the same arguments then won't be distinguished from each other, despite having different template arguments.

Answer (score -1):

it's because you've got two functions `solve` with the same signature. Change the second to be `solve(Body a, Body b, Body& c = zero)`